# Datagridview checkbox column's value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a checkbox column. I want to capture the value of the checkbox immediately when user changes it by clicking. I tried several events (`CellValueChanged`, `CellClicked`, `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` etc.) but nothing worked.

This is my code:

```
If dgvIDsTBC.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = True Then
    MsgBox("True")
End If
```

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps

```
void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString());
}
```

This i presume you would have done, now the catch is unless you move out of the cell the grid considers you are still editing ,So Add this part

```
void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
       dataGridView1.EndEdit();
}
```

This should be fine for you, 3 is the checkbox column you intend it to work for